# (From / Size) in elasticsearch query does not return expected doc

Tags: elasticsearch

because when I use the (From / Size) function in the query, it doesn't return the doc that I hope to return. For example, I have 5 docs in elasticsearch, all docs in the sequence, _id 1, _id 2, _id 3, _id 4, id _5.

The doc ID 5 has the word (car) and In the query I say to get the word (car) from ID 4 ("from": 4, "size": 1,) it does not return the ID 5 it has the word (car), but in the query I put information that exists in doc 5, so I should bring doc 5, but it doesn't and says it didn't find a result. If I put the query from ID 0 ("from": 0, "size": 1,) it finds ID 5. It seems that elasticsearch makes confusion with ID's. Can you tell me what happens to ID's?

The query below from ID 4 does not return ID 5, but if I put the query from ID 0, then it returns ID 5

```
{
"from": 4, "size": 1,
"query": {
"multi_match": {
"query": "car",

   "type": "cross_fields",
   "fields": ["title", "description", "url"],
   "operator": "and"
}
}
}
```

Comment: From and size are for pagination of records returned by query. If your query(search on car) returns five records then from:4 size : 1 will return 5th record. If your query returns only 1 record then from:4 size:0 will not return anything as there is no 5 th record in result

Comment: @jaspreet 

but I didn't put size (zero) ("from": 4, "size": 0) I put ("from": 4, "size": 1), so I should bring the _id 5 that has the word (car)

Answer (score 0):

`size` and `from` are applied *after* the query filters are applied.

Also, your "sorted" doc IDs don't necessarily guarantee the retrieval order, esp. when scoring comes into play.

If you share your docs & mapping, we could help you out further.

Answer (score 0):

in the query below I send the results that have the field (pgrk) between 9 and 10 and have the field (url_length) less than 4, but the record with (_id 15) satisfies what I requested, but only returns the record of (_id 15) if I put ("from": 0,"size": 1,) if I put ("from": 1,"size": 1,) does not return the record (_id 15)

```
{
    "from": 1,
    "size": 1,
    "sort": [
        {
            "pgrk": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        },
        {
            "url_length": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "netflix",
                    "type": "cross_fields",
                    "fields": [
                        "titulo",
                        "descricao",
                        "url"
                    ],
                    "operator": "and"
                }
            },
            "filter": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "pgrk": {
                            "gte": 9,
                            "lte" : 10
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "url_length": {
                           "lt" : 4
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

if I put ("from": 1, "size": 1,) it does not return the record (_id 15) that has "url_length = 2" returns the doc of _id 14 that has "url_length = 3" as shown below:

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 2,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "teste",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "14",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "url": "www.333.com",
          "titulo": "netflix netflix netflix netflix netflix netflix netflix netflix netflix netflix",
          "descricao": "tudo sobre netflix netflix netflix netflix netflix netflix",
          "pgrk": "10",
          "url_length": "3"
        },
        "sort": [
          10,
          3
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

if I put ("from": 0, "size": 1,) then it returns the record (_id 15) that has "url_length = 2"

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 2,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "teste",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "15",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "url": "www.netflix.yahoo.com",
          "titulo": "melhor filme",
          "descricao": "tudo sobre series",
          "pgrk": "10",
          "url_length": "2"
        },
        "sort": [
          10,
          2
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```